# Что делать если в azure vm недоступен нужный регион?

Tags: azure

При создании azure vm доступны только центральный регион сша, юго-восточная азия, западная япония, восточная япония. И недоступны другие регионы (нужен регион западная европа). В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Писать в саппорт Azure? Возможно вы выбрали какой-то специфический шаблон? Или размер? Или просто напоролись на глюк портала (нового или старого)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может кому-то будет полезно. В azure на данный момент есть две модели развёртывания vm классическая и через диспетчер ресурсов. На старом портале есть только классическая у неё сейчас ограничения по регионам, а вот через диспетчер ресурсов ограничений нет. Собственно решение проблемы простое - создавать vm на новом портале с помощью диспетчера ресурсов.

Comment: ВАУ! Спасибо за информацию! Я уже весь гугл облазил в поисках этой информации!